# How to solve "Name error" in Python tkinter programme?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mylabel = label(root, text = "What's up?")
mylabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code I used in Visual code studio. And it shows me an error:

`NameError: name 'label' is not defined`

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Well, it says that there was an error to do with a name, and the name that it says has the problem is `'label'`. So, presumably, the part of the code you need to change is the part that says `label`. If you were expecting that to work as-is, the next steps are to proof-read the code, and re-check the documentation. Also remember that Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls change your code like this

```
mylabel = Label(root,text = '')
```

you should use Lable instead label